# How to split/copy a FIFO without using a file

Tags: bash

I want to split a FIFO to be able to analyze the copy without loosing the original contents:

```
cat < outfile | tee > outfile2 | tee > outfile3 &

declare DONE=
until [ $DONE ]; do
    IFS= read -r -d '}' line || DONE=1
    { [ "${line: -12}" == '{ready123450' ] || [ "${line: -13}" == '{ready_123450' ]; } && {
        DONE=1
        echo "> $line"
    }
done < <( cat < outfile2 & )
```

This part works. I know when the producer has finished writing bytes (without closing the pipe). After that I want to output the full original content:

```
cat < outfile3
```

The problem: It does not output anything, although `tee` should have started redirecting the contents of outfile2 as soon as I started reading the lines. I need to preserve the content of outfile, probably by buffering it. I cannot do this with `read line` because this is raw binary data, and bash variables cannot contain null bytes. Is this possible without using a file or the `buffer` command?

Comment: That code... makes many useless things. That's useless use of `cat` : `cat <something |` is equal to `< something`. The first line is just `tee  outfile2 outfile3 < outfile &`. `<( cat < outfile2 & )` - why `&`.

Comment: Your very first pipeline doesn't not work on `outfile3`, it will remain an empty file

Comment: @KamilCuk 1) This is not correct: `outfile*` are FIFOs, and the first part won't work if I omit `<` before the FIFO names. Works for me for the first part: `tee > outfile2 < outfile | tee < outfile3 &` Does not work: `tee > outfile2 > outfile3 < outfile &` But the outfile3 FIFO still does not output anything. 2) You are right, I can omit the `&`. I use Bash v3.2.

Comment: @Inian Why will this FIFO stay empty? This is my question.

Comment: Remove the `>` .... _not_ `tee > outfile2 > outfile3 < outfile &` Do `tee outfile2 outfile3 < outfile &`. Please research what `tee` does and what redirection operator does in shell. `Why will this FIFO stay empty?` Because you are redirecting the output to `outfile2` , so the next command will receive nothing. Running `tee` without arguments is just useless.

Comment: @KamilCuk Result: I get no output at all with this: `tee outfile2 outfile3 < outfile & cat < outfile2` – no result. With `tee > outfile2 < outfile & cat < outfile2` I get an output of the full result. So how do I copy the tee input (outfile) to the outfile2 FIFO?

Comment: __Little Update__: I remove the first line, and the feeding of the loop is `tee outfile2 < outfile`. Result: no output from the loop and not output from `cat < outfile2`.